# Create custom pages on Ghost

Tags: nginx, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm looking to add some more .hbs files to ghost/custom/themes/casper, such as an about page and landing page. This way, all files are using the same default layout and I have a /blog destination for my blog.

However, when I create an .hbs file, such as about.hbs, and give it the same code as in page.hbs, and upload it to the theme folder, when I go to my-url.com/about, it gives a 404.

So, how can I create custom .hbs pages?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, make sure to restart Ghost after making the changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create the page with the specific slug in the Ghost backend.
2. Create the `.hbs`-file named like this: `page-about.hbs`.

From [Ghost Documentation on custom pages](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/page-context):

> For example, if you have an '*About*' page with the url `/about/`, adding a template called `page-about.hbs` will cause that template to be used for the about page, instead of `page.hbs`, or `post.hbs`.
>
> These templates exist in a hierarchy. Ghost looks for a template which matches the slug (`page-:slug.hbs`) first, then looks for `page.hbs` and finally uses post.hbs if neither is available.

Comment: So I've created and uploaded a file `page-about.hbs`. I then did a `service ghost restart`, restarting Ghost. However I still a 404 error when visiting my-ip/about.

Comment: Did you delete the old `about.hbs`-file?

Comment: Yes. All the default files are there as well as the `page-about.hbs` file.

Comment: The only things left to troubleshoot is if you are running a fairly recent version of Ghost and that you have actually created the page with that slug in the admin GUI.

Comment: Ah, creating the page was the solution. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I could be of help :)

Comment: I have created page-signup.hbs and added the route in yml ``` routes:
  /signup/:
    template: signup``` .. but getting redirected to http://localhost:2368/ghost/#/signup/

Comment: My best guess is that either the page isn't created through the GUI or it could be that `/signup` is reserved for Ghost Core.